# Telescope receiving empty responses even though there are records in the database that it should show

Tags: laravel

Telescope doesn't display any records from the `telescope_entries` table, but instead it only shows this:

[image]

If we take a look into the browser console, we will see that Telescope frequently sends POST requests to its API, but receives an empty array of entries:

[image]

I am sure that there are records in the database, because I can see them using my database viewer:

[image]

Also when I run `DB::table("telescope_entries")->get()` in Tinker I get the proper records from the database.

For debugging purposes I added `lad([$request, $storage]);` before the return statement in the `index` method in `EntryController`:

```
public function index(Request $request, EntriesRepository $storage)
{
    lad([$request, $storage]); // function comes from lanin/laravel-api-debugger
    return response()->json([
        'entries' => $storage->get(
            $this->entryType(),
            EntryQueryOptions::fromRequest($request)
        ),
        'status' => $this->status(),
    ]);
}
```

Now when the browser send the request to Telescope's API, it receives the following JSON:

```
{
    "entries": [],
    "status": "enabled",
    "debug": {
        "database": {
            "total": 1,
            "items": [
                {
                    "connection": "sqlite",
                    "query": "select * from \"telescope_entries\" where \"type\" = 'request' and \"should_display_on_index\" = '1' order by \"sequence\" desc limit 50;",
                    "time": 7.68
                }
            ]
        },
        "cache": {
            "hit": {
                "keys": [],
                "total": 0
            },
            "miss": {
                "keys": [
                    "telescope:dump-watcher",
                    "telescope:pause-recording"
                ],
                "total": 2
            },
            "write": {
                "keys": [],
                "total": 0
            },
            "forget": {
                "keys": [],
                "total": 0
            }
        },
        "profiling": [
            {
                "event": "request-time",
                "time": 0.6450369358062744
            }
        ],
        "memory": {
            "usage": 16327024,
            "peak": 16547112
        },
        "dump": [
            [
                {
                    "attributes": {},
                    "request": {},
                    "query": {},
                    "server": {},
                    "files": {},
                    "cookies": {},
                    "headers": {}
                },
                {}
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

When I run the SQL statement provided above in my database viewer, I receive the records that I should be receiving:

[image]

This issue seems to be database independent. I connected to an external PostgreSQL database as well as to a local SQLite database and the same issue occurred.

I'm stuck with this since I first started with Laravel and literally I can't do anything about it. I posted an issue on Telescope's GitHub but it got closed because "It worked for someone else".

Steps I made to recreate this issue:

1. Created a new Laravel project
2. Set the `DB_CONNECTION` variable in `.env` file to `sqlite`
3. Created a new file called `database.sqlite` in the `/database` folder
4. Ran commands:

   1. `composer require laravel/telescope`
   2. `php artisan telescope:install`
   3. `php artisan migrate`

Also, I'm not in production nor I did anything more than the above. Telescope also doesn't work for me if I use a project created by someone else, but for that person it works.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to run Laravel on Homestead. I'm probably missing a package of some sort, I'm too tired to investigate. I can recommend a tutorial which I used to get it going:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2RAArt1GRI